# How do I launch Slack on startup Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: slack

How do I launch Slack on startup Ubuntu 20.04?

Do I need to [configure it manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) as I do with some other programs, or is there a special option in Slack to do it for me?

Answer (score 5):

In my version (Ubuntu 22.04, Slack 4.29) you can find that option under File -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Other options -> Launch app on login

Answer (score 2):

Applications may provide an option to enable autostart. If they don't, [the answer you are linking to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login) provides instructions on how you can autostart any application. An application that exposes the option actually uses the exact same mechanism.